# Python Storing Dynamic Command inside Dynamic Variable

Tags: python-3.x, list, python-requests

I've got this list:

```
appliances = [{'firewall': 'Washington', 'firewall_endpoint': '192.168.1.254:443'}, {'firewall': 'Atlanta', 'firewall_endpoint': '10.8.6.1:6565'}]
```

This list can be dynamic as appliances are added to the network.  I found some code that creates dynamic variables based on the item in the list:

```
for num in range(len(appliances)):
    exec(f'firewall_endpoint_'+str(num)+'_session = firewallhost[num]')
```

I'm able to print out a list of current variables and you can see it creates the two *firewall_endpoint_x* variables:

```
['firewall_endpoint_0', 'firewall_endpoint_1', 'time', 'requests', 'sys', 'pprint', 'json', 'socket', 'struct', 'ipaddress', 'InsecureRequestWarning', 'username', 'password', 'FGT', 'appliances', 'num']
```

Here is an example of how to login to one session:

```
fgt=FGT(ipaddress:port)
fgt.login(name=username, key=password)
```

I'm trying to login to both of them at the same time so both of them have their own session.  The syntax is all messed up.  I have no idea what the right syntax is

```
username = admin
password = password123

class FGT(object):
   def login(self, name, key):
        url = self.url_prefix + '/logincheck'
        res = self.session.post(url,
                                data='username=' + name + '&secretkey=' + key,
                                verify = False)
if type(appliances) == list:
        ## Create dynamic list of firewall variables and login
        for num in range(len(firewallhost)):
            exec(f'firewall_endpoint_'+str(num)+'_session = FGT(firewallhost[num][firewall_endpoint]).login(username, password)')
```

Comment: " I found some code that creates dynamic variables based on the item in the list" Why? *don't do that*. It's a terrible practice, and it is never necessary. Just use a *container* like a `list` or a `dict`.

Comment: Can you give me an example?